# Once Count up features reaches 24hr it resets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My current count up script resets to 0:00 when it reaches 24hours

I thought it could be something in the formatting of the cell and tried adding the date but not working.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var TIME_ZONE = "GMT+2"; 
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIME_ZONE,'hh:mm:ss a');


  //if column A has been edited, set date in same row in column B
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 2).setValue(date);

   var countdownrange = e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 4);
   countdownrange.setFormulaR1C1("=R[0]C[-1]-R[0]C[-2]");
   var nowrange = e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 3);
   nowrange.setFormula("=NOW()");
  }
}
```

I want it to count up longer than 24hours, so 48hr etc

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIME_ZONE,'hh:mm:ss a');
```

please try:

```
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIME_ZONE,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a');
```